# What alternatives I have against sleep() to synchronize transfer between parent and child process?

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm facing a synchronization problem, the problem I'm trying to solve involves sending string from parent to child, reversing it and sending it back to child ( using shared memory ).

However to make sure child is waiting for parent I'm using `sleep(3)` to give `3` seconds to parent process to enter string, however this is limiting my programs efficiency, I don't want to force user to wait for 3 seconds.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* Needed for the wait function */
#include <unistd.h>    /* needed for the fork function */
#include <string.h>    /* needed for the strcat function */
#define SHMSIZE 27

int main() {
    int shmid;
    char *shm;

    if(fork() == 0) {
        sleep(3);
        shmid = shmget(29009, SHMSIZE, 0);
        shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        printf ("Child : Reading %s \n",shm) ;
        int len=strlen(shm);
        char rev[100],temp;

        int i = 0;
        int j = strlen(shm) - 2;

        while (i < j) {
            temp = shm[i];
            shm[i] = shm[j];
            shm[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        shmdt(shm);

    }else {
        shmid = shmget(29009, SHMSIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

        printf("Parent : Enter String \n ");
        char *s = (char *) shm;
        *s = '\0';
        char a[100];
        fgets(a,100,stdin);
        strcat(s,a);
        printf ("Parent: sending %s \n",shm);
        sleep(3);
        printf("Parent: receiving %s" ,shm);
        shmdt(shm);

   }
   return 0;
}
```

### Question:

1. How could this be implemented in a better way, so that the program is more efficient?

Comment: Use a shared semaphore maybe?

Comment: Perhaps shared memory is not the right option.

Comment: Well, normally, this communication would be done by pipes, but I assumed  OP's assignment is to do it with shared memory

Comment: @IrinaAvram just did, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to amazing StackOverflow community for coming to my rescue! I have resolved solved the issue using semaphores! I'm sharing my final code so it can be of use for anyone who gets struck in a situation like mine!

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* Needed for the wait function */
#include <unistd.h>    /* needed for the fork function */
#include <string.h>    /* needed for the strcat function */
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SHMSIZE 27
typedef struct {
    sem_t one;
    sem_t two;
} SemPair;
int main() {


 int shm = shm_open("/test", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ftruncate(shm, sizeof(sem_t));
    SemPair *sem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0);

 sem_init(&(sem->one), 1, 0);
 sem_init(&(sem->two), 1, 0);

   int shmid;
   char *shmz;

   if(fork() == 0) {
      sem_wait(&(sem->one));
      shmid = shmget(29009, SHMSIZE, 0);
      shmz = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      printf ("Child : Reading %s \n",shmz) ;
      int len=strlen(shmz);
      char rev[100],temp;
 int  i = 0;
   int   j = strlen(shmz) - 2;
   while (i < j) {
      temp = shmz[i];
      shmz[i] = shmz[j];
      shmz[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
   }


    shmdt(shmz);
    sem_post(&(sem->two));
   }
   else {
      shmid = shmget(29009, SHMSIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
      shmz = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

      printf("Parent : Enter String \n ");
      char *s = (char *) shmz;
      *s = '\0';
      char a[100];
      fgets(a,100,stdin);
      strcat(s,a);
      printf ("Parent: sending %s \n",shmz);
      sem_post(&(sem->one));
      sem_wait(&(sem->two));
      printf("Parent: receiving %s" ,shmz);
      shmdt(shmz);

}
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using semaphores, this is not a case where you use 'sleep':
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html

You can use them like in this example:
http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html

You cannot know for sure that it will not take more than 3 seconds, so sleep is a realy bad choice. So, it goes something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <semaphore.h>


int main(void)
{
sem_t *sem = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
              MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

sem_init(sem, 1, 1);

if(fork() == 0) {
    printf("Child: Waiting to acquire semaphore\n");
    sem_wait(sem);
    printf("Child acquires lock\n");
    /* do whatever you want then relese*/
    sem_post(sem);
} else {
    printf("Parent: Waiting to acquire semaphore\n");
    sem_wait(sem);
    printf("Parent acquires lock\n");
    /* do whatever you want then relese*/
    sem_post(sem);
}

sem_destroy(sem);
return 0;
}
```

Oh and if you want it parent to be followed by child always (or the other way around), you can use two semaphores, and initialize them accordingly(with 1 and 0, or 0 and 1).

```
    sem_wait(sem1);
    printf("Parent acquires lock\n");
    /* do whatever you want then relese*/
    sem_post(sem2);

/* Other things will be happening here */

    sem_wait(sem2);
    printf("Child acquires lock\n");
    /* do whatever you want then relese*/
    sem_post(sem1);
```

**Edit**

If you do not have to use shared memory, it would be better to do the communication with sockets.

Comment: Please don't link to linux.die.net.